# Highlight selected tab in Xamarin Forms UWP

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp, xamarin.uwp

I'm currently creating my own app using Xamarin forms in VS 2015. Now for testing purposes it was easiest to use the Universal Windows app, but I seem to be stuck with one single point; the selected tab doesn't highlight in anyway.

The highlighting is not exactly the one I want, more to illustrate:

[Actual behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4xmtU.png)

[Expected behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nxxf0.png)

As for the code I'm using, the main `App` loads a `new NavigationPage(new Layout.SchedulePage())` where the schedule page is the actual culprit, extending Xamarin.Forms.TabbedPage. The SelectedPage gets set correctly (loads the correct contentpage) but the tab doesn't highlight.

After extensive research, I have ruled out the following:

- I have looked at the Extended TabbedPage from XLabs but it doesn't seem to have anything to do with the selected tab style.
- I have looked at a custom renderer for the tabbedpage, but that doesn't allow modifying a single tab as far as I have seen, only the collective data template

So, my question resolves to be:

**How do I modify the style of the selected tab xamarin forms, or does UWP not have this capability?**

I can provide additional code if necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need to do for UWP is override the default pivot header style.
You can copy / paste it from here : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299142.aspx

Inside it, you'll notice several VisualStates, look for the 'Selected' one. In that one, the 'Background' is being manipulated to 'SystemControlHighlightTransparentBrush' meaning it's set to Transparant. Just paste in the color brush you want in here to adjust this.

You can see I do the same in an App I've created here : https://github.com/AppCreativity/Kliva/blob/505f944411ca40e1622186b323c60297eeb2788a/src/Kliva/XAMLResources/Styles.xaml#L1211

Comment: I'll take a look when I'm home, but it seems to be perfect, thanks!

Comment: yup, I solved it. An alternative to changing the brush would be creating a visualstate.setter the background as target.